# Show Sql in Jhipster 4.4.1

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I added a new connection to my Jhipster application:

```
data:
    mongodb:
        uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
        database: crm
datasources:    
    elser:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/elser
        name: elser
        username: elser
        password: elser
```

I want to see in the sql logs that my connection to Postgres generates.

I have tested by adding the following code in 'application-dev.yml':

```
jpa:
  properties:
    hibernate:
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
```

or:

```
jpa:
    show_sql: true
    format_sql: true
```

But neither option worked for me.

Can somebody help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to spring docs setting `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` should do the trick.
Have you checked if it appears in stdout?

From the spring boot docs:

```
# JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true # Enable JPA repositories.
spring.jpa.database= # Target database to operate on, auto-detected by default. Can be alternatively set using the "databasePlatform" property.
spring.jpa.database-platform= # Name of the target database to operate on, auto-detected by default. Can be alternatively set using the "Database" enum.
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false # Initialize the schema on startup.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Default to "create-drop" when using an embedded database, "none" otherwise.
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy= # Hibernate 5 implicit naming strategy fully qualified name.
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy= # Hibernate 5 physical naming strategy fully qualified name.
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy= # Hibernate 4 naming strategy fully qualified name. Not supported with Hibernate 5.
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= # Use Hibernate's newer IdentifierGenerator for AUTO, TABLE and SEQUENCE.
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true # Register OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request.
spring.jpa.properties.*= # Additional native properties to set on the JPA provider.
spring.jpa.show-sql=false # Enable logging of SQL statements.
```